# How to install C/C++ development libraries (like GLEW, SDL2, Lua52) under Windows 10 with MinGW+Cmake

Tags: windows, cmake, path, mingw, libraries

It is very long time (~20 years) since I tried last time to program something in C/C++ under Windows, and I completely forgot how it works.

I have some [project](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/SimpleSimulationEngine) using GLEW, SDL2 and Lua52 under Linux, but my friend wants to compile it under windows.
I installed MinGW and cmake under windows, and downloaded the .zip files with the libraries (lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin.zip, lua-5.2.4_Win64_dllw6_lib.zip, SDL2-devel-2.0.12-mingw.tar.gz, SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-mingw.tar.gz )

What I don't see, where should I unpack these files so that Cmake can find them?
In Linux I install the libraries from system repo, and then corresponding .cmake scripts can find the automatically use some helper files like (FindSDL2.cmake, FindSDL2_mixer.cmake, FindLua52.cmake) but I don't see how to do this under Windows where is no such central repo-manager I have to unpack the libs in some folder manually.

I want to avoid manual setup of PATHS, since this I always mess up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Linux background you should definitively use the MSYS2 environment (https://www.msys2.org/). It comes with a bash shell and a package manager.